# Which software is used to produce this video?

Tags: animation, software

Its an animation video. Can someone specify the software ? [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5LICH9PiIU)

Comment: Welcome! That could have been made with almost any animation tool. It is more about technique than software. Is there a particular technique from a section of that video that you are interested in doing in an application you are familiar with?

Comment: Thank you! I am just a beginner. Can you tell me about the technique used from 2:20 to 2:30. Also please do recommend some software which can be used to do the same with minimal effort.

Comment: I like the do the same... with minimal effort part.

Comment: You can do it with minimal effort by hiring an animator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is maybe ToonBoom.

But regardless what software they used to stitch the final cut together, there were a host of software applications involved.

Illustration, likely Adobe Illustrator and Photoshop, Compositing, Could be ToonBoom, AfterEffects, or others. Audio was done separately, on the tail end. And I jumped over myself, they likely storyboarded all of the animations out in advance, ToonBoom, likely a good choice for that even if it's not what they used for the final mesh.

In addition, they undoubtably used a host of plugins, perhaps some free, some paid, some very expensive to assist with the motion control and character animation. And last, they likely also relied of pre-existing works, templates, which can be purchased.